# Desktop keeps dropping off internet, modem working, wireless devices working

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, dns, modem

Super strange for the last 3 weeks, I go to use my desktop and I can't get on the internet. I get message in my browser that it can't get the page. Yet I look at my modem lights and the internet light is okay and my wireless devices function just fine. It's just my desktop. I tried using different plug-ins in the back of my modem/router for my desktop and I still get the same issue. I do have a second router attached to provide signal to other parts of the house.  I have never had any issues like this and been using it this way for about 8 years just fine.

Currently to get online with my desktop I have to access the modem through my browser.  I then disconnect it, wait 10 seconds and re-connect through the browser. Some days I have to do this say 7 or 8 times, or every 15 minutes.

Any ideas - Once Windows Network Diagnostics gave me a message that the dns was not connecting, however the wireless was working fine. Any suggestions on what to look at?

Kim

Comment: Ensure you're using the same DNS server(s) as other devices that work; and/or try a different DNS provider.

Comment: I am using the same DNS services and going with another is not an option.  Anyone else having this issue and figured out a way to resolve it?

Comment: I have tried different things now.  I have unplugged everything, reset and have only my desktop plugged into the router/modem.  I still have the same issue and my browser can not open up websites and my email can not connect.  Yet I can use a wireless device it functions flawlessly, when my desktop browser says it can not.  The Gateway says the connection is up, but I can't not get the browsers to work.  I have to end the ppp session, then reconnect before it functions.   I have tried safari, chrome, IE, and firefox all fail.